# How to map phone number with Cognito User Pool Federated to Google

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-signin, amazon-cognito

According to [Scopes for Google SignIn](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#google_sign-in), there is no 'phone' scope, the only scopes are openid, email, profile.

My Cognito User Pool has a phone user attribute, and it is required.

For users who sign-up directly with the user pool, they enter their phone number in Amazon's hosted UI which displays a phone field in the sign up form, all good.

For users who sign-up with Google, they get an error. I've traced it to the fact that Google doesn't send over a phone_number and the mapping from Google to User Pools attribute fails. If I create a new pool, which does not require a phone_number federation to Google works, the moment I require that attribute it fails, despite the fact that the Google Account I test with has a phone_number.

**Is mapping phone really not possible when sign in with Google federated to Cognito User Pool?**

**Is it possible for the the hosted SignUp UI to show a field for my Google users asking them to fill in the phone number between them authenticating with Google and the hosted UI redirecting to my redirect URL?**

**Alternate solutions?**

Comment: Hi mipnw, did you find the sollution? I'm having the same problem here.

Comment: That was about a year ago so I don't remember precisely the outcome of this particular question. I think this issue with AWS user pools was one of many issues I encountered with AWS for app authentication, weird OAUTH behaviors, poor documentation, poor mobile APIs, and eventually I just dropped AWS authentication altogether.

Comment: Even i encountered with the same issue. Even though we add ***https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read*** in identity providers on userpool, it still seeks for a phone number. Google Contacts API send phone number, but the mobile number format for google is different with that of cognito, hence cognito throws ***invalid phone number format***

Comment: Hi running into the same issue, were you able to find any solution? Tried adding the googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read scope in google console and mapped it in my aws account as well but it throws an error where it is not able to find the phone number.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue. To get this to "work" I had to sadly remove the phone number requirement which also meant I had to make a new user pool.

Answer (score 0):

Now AWS provides phone scope

**Step-1** Go to user pool's  **App client settings** page.
**Step-2** click the phone option.
[image]

**Step-3**  Go to user pool's  **Attribute Mapping page** page.

**Step-4** Map external identity provider's attribute to user pool attribute. (I am using Google)
[image]